# How to print this pattern in PL/SQL

Tags: for-loop, plsql, nested, nested-loops

```
   *
   # *
   * # *
   # * # *
   * # * # *
```

how can i print this pattern in PL/SQL

```
declare
    c number:=1;
    i number;
    j number;
begin 
    for i in 1..5
    loop 
        for j in 1..i
        loop
            dbms_output.put(*);
        end loop;

        dbms_output.new_line;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

i have tries this but don't know how to include # position wise

Answer (score 0):

> [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=372d1d7b845443ef2b44238ce8634b39)

```
declare
  
  v_char varchar2(1);
  v_outer_loop number := 5;
  v_inner_loop number := 1;
  
  function get_next_char(p_current_char in varchar2) return varchar2
  is
  begin
    if p_current_char = '*' then
      return '#';
      else
      return '*';
    end if;
  end get_next_char;

begin
  for i in 1..v_outer_loop loop
      v_char := case when mod(i,2)> 0 then '*' else '#' end;
      for j in 1..v_inner_loop loop
        dbms_output.put(v_char);
        v_char := get_next_char(v_char);
      end loop;
      v_inner_loop := v_inner_loop + 1;
      dbms_output.new_line;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped a lot!